# Set embedded video not autoplay on page load?

Tags: video, video-richmedia

I embed video from near site and it autostarts every time the page loads. I want to turn it off, or(ideally) - I'd like to manage this autoplay option via checkbox. Youtube videos have this [autoplay](https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters?hl=en#autoplay) option, but it does not work in sharepoint embed videos(video always start to play).

[image]

Does Sharepoint have some ability to turn off autoplay?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you user "Embed" option for inserting media files, SharePoint does not allow to control "Atuotplay" properties. Instead, you can use other alternatives like upload from Computer or SharePoint.

Refer this link for more details:
http://community.bamboosolutions.com/blogs/sharepoint-2013/archive/2013/04/01/how-to-insert-media-to-a-site-page-in-sharepoint-2013.aspx

Comment: thank You for response! Very interesting, I'll try Your method tomorrow and ping You back!

Comment: Dead link: the bamboosolutions.com site has changed.

Comment: Further note: the information in this answer does not apply to SharePoint Online.